# Erlang OTP 21 How to disable logger console output

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

According to erlang documentation is is possibe to configure logger for file only:

from [Erlang Documentation:](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/logger_chapter.html#logger_parameter)

Modify the default handler to print to a file instead of standard_io:

```
[{kernel,
[{logger,
  [{handler, default, logger_std_h,  % {handler, HandlerId, Module,Config}
    #{config => #{file => "log/erlang.log"}}}
]}]}].
```

My config file looks like:

```
 [{kernel,[
  {logger_level, error},
  {logger,
    [{handler, default, logger_std_h,
      #{config => #{file => "log/erlang.log"}}}
    ]
   }
  ]}].
```

i.o. exactly as in the documentation. 
 with log level set to **error**

When I stat application using **reabar3 shell** following printed into console:

```
===> The rebar3 shell is a development tool; to deploy applications in production, consider using releases (http://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases)
2019-04-10T15:14:33.363287+02:00 info: application: syntax_tools, started_at: 'node@x201'
2019-04-10T15:14:33.371897+02:00 info: application: compiler, started_at: 'node@x201'
2019-04-10T15:14:33.379962+02:00 info: supervisor: {local,gr_sup}, started: [{pid,<0.1181.0>},{id,gr_counter_sup},{mfargs,{gr_counter_sup,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,5000},{child_type,supervisor}]
2019-04-10T15:14:33.382379+02:00 info: supervisor: {local,gr_sup}, started: [{pid,<0.1182.0>},{id,gr_param_sup},{mfargs,{gr_param_sup,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,5000},{child_type,supervisor}]
```

So, OTP progress messages are **not** redirected to the file, but still printed to the console and file **erlang.log** is empty.

How to disable console output and redirect all messages to the file?

P.S. Erlang version:

```
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.3.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After fighting for a while I  found a problem:

- In case of a wrong parameter, Logger just do not create file.
- Looks like documentation is incomplete

  [{kernel,
  [{logger,
  [{handler, default, logger_std_h,  % {handler, HandlerId, Module,Config}
     #{config => #{file => "log/erlang.log"}}}
  ]}]}].

  **{config => #{file => "log/erlang.log"}}**

should be changed to:

**#{config => #{ type => {file => "log/erlang.log"}}}}**

```
 [{kernel,
 [{logger,
  [{handler, default, logger_std_h,  % {handler, HandlerId, Module,Config}
   #{config => #{ type => {file => "log/erlang.log"}}}}
]}]}].
```

Here: [Complete example of logger configuration file](https://github.com/ad-pro/logger.config/blob/master/config/logger.config)

Comment: If it is indeed a bug in the documentation it could be reported to https://bugs.erlang.org

Comment: Thanks  a lot. Just report it there

Comment: It is not a bug in the documentation. Instead, the configuration format changed between OTP 21 and OTP 22. It you look at the OTP 21 documentation, it contains the format that you say works for you: http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-10.0/lib/kernel-6.0/doc/html/logger.html

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
{logger, [
{handler,default,undefined}
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

(supernode@127.0.0.1)14> logger:set_primary_config(level, none).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.